# Iterating through subdirectories and get two files as arguments for awk script

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk

I need to iterate through the subdirectories of a directory and take two of the files, as arguments of an awk script. The script will compare the two files and generate other files.

I've this. But I need awk script to take as an argument files. ".*1.txt" and        ".*2.txt"

```
for i in words/*/*1.txt words/*/*2.txt
do 
awk -f corpus_vs_flexion.awk "$i"
done
```

Something like:

```
awk -f corpus_vs_flexion.awk .*1.txt .*2.txt
# Taking them from each subdirectory in words/* 

Directory words/
               subdirectory Peter/
                                 whatever.txt
                                 whatever1.txt
                                 whatever.txt
                                 whatever.txt
                                 whatever2.txt
               subdirectory Blas/
                                 whatever1.txt
                                 whatever.txt
                                 whatever.txt
                                 whatever.txt
                                 whatever2.txt
               ........./
                                 .....
                                 ..
For each subdirectory loop: awk -f corpus_vs_flexion.awk whatever1.txt whatever2.txt
```

Comment: So what are the pairs? `words/Peter/whatever1.txt` and `words/Blas/whatever2.txt`? `words/Peter/whatever1.txt` and `words/Peter/whatever2.txt`? Are the pairs always in the same directory?

Comment: words/Peter/whatever1.txt and words/Peter/whatever2.txt are the pairs always in the same directory. For words/Peter/ `awk -f corpus_vs_flexion.awk whatever1.txt whatever2.txt` for words/Blas/ `awk -f corpus_vs_flexion.awk whatever1.txt whatever2.txt`

Comment: OK, please [edit] your question and clarify that there are always _pairs_ in the directories. Your multiple `/same/path/whatever.txt` are confusing. Also, will the files _always_ end in `1.txt` and `2.txt`? Or can we have `3.txt` and `4.txt` or anything else?

Comment: If what you found solved your problem (and it looks like it does), add it as an answer and accept it if nobody comes up with another answer that you like better - it's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question on this site.  Answers do not belong embedded in questions.

Comment: @cas You're right!! Done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, with file names occurring in matching pairs, you could use the following:

```
for f in words/*/*1.txt ; do awk -f corpus_vs_flexion.awk "$f" "${f%1.txt}2.txt" ; done
```

The `"${f%1.txt}2.txt"` phrase says "use the filename of `"$f"` but remove the ending `1.txt` and add ending `2.txt` instead".

Comment: Files to process in each subdirectory. End in "1.txt" and "2.txt". Example: "blabla1.txt" or "blublu2.txt", plus there may be more files with other different names. Then I have to use a regular expression to process

Answer (score 2):

I have been reading a bash book, and I found what I needed!

```
typ1_files=(words/*/*1.txt)
typ2_files=(words/*/*2.txt)

for ((i=0;i<=${#typ1_files[@]};i++)); do
   awk -f corpus_vs_flexion.awk "${typ1_files[i]}" "${typ2_files[i]}"
done
```

Comment: i'm unsure if your answer or @Ralph's answer is better.  Both assume that there will always be a matching 2.txt for each 1.txt.  Your answer has the potential to get out of sync (with elements from typ1_files not corresponding to matching elements from typ2_files - i.e. referring to unrelated 2.txt files in another directory) and messing up the entire run from the point that synchronisation failed.  Ralph's answer will fail only for the specific file(s) where a matching 2.txt doesn't exist, a far less disastrous failure mode - i've changed my mind, Ralph's answer is better as it's safer.

Comment: A simple safety net would be to add a line like `[[ ${#typ1_files[@]} = ${#typ2_files[@]} ]] || exit` so it will exit the program if the number of files in each array isn't the same.

Comment: yep. OTOH, that would also fail in the same way if there were 2.txt files without matching 1.txt files, so that the count remained equal.  probably not an issue in real life with this set of files, but it's always worthwhile being paranoid and thinking about what **could** go wrong and programming defensively to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can be sure your file search is exhaustive and not matching other files, simplify by losing the `for` loop and just use a command substitution with `find`.

```
awk -f corpus_vs_flexion.awk $(find /path/to/your/dir -name "*.txt" -type f | tr '\n' ' ')
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Put your dir here
```

Comment: I have to process, whatever 1.txt and whatever2.txt at the same time, in each loop. `awk -f corpus_vs_flexion.awk whatever1.txt whatever2.txt` for each subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

I like Ralph's answer. This might also work (untested)

```
find. -name '*[12].txt' -print0 | xargs -0 -n 2 awk '...'
```